# remote linux server shutdowns instead of reboot

Tags: linux, suse

When I tried to reboot my remote linux server with reboot command the server shuts down. Command used:

```
linux-ozzesh:~ # reboot
```

Why is this happening? Isn't there any other command that would restart my server instead of shutdown?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your `reboot` command **alias** to `shutdown` check it! Try to exec this command:

> shutdown -r now

and feedback here what happens.

Comment: You could also use `init 6` instead of the shutdown command.

Answer (score 0):

That command certainly should restart it and not shut it down. You could try "shutdown -r now"
I'm guessing you are already using root privileges?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **f** flag. From the `reboot` `man` page:

```
-f, --force
          Does not invoke shutdown(8)  and  instead  performs  the  actual
          action you would expect from the name.
```

So you should invoke this command:

```
user@host:~ # reboot -f
```